# Using getComputedStyle() doesn't return the correct style value for a Polymer core-input

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

Using `getComputedStyle()` to read a style from my `core-input` doesn't seem to return the correct value.

```
print(getComputedStyle('core-input').lineHeight);
```

By actual value, I mean what's set in my CSS, and what Chrome's "Computed" styles tab tells me. The above prints "normal" whereas it's actually "16px".

If I set the style programmatically, it does seem to work.